# How to disable WebGL in Chrome on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, webgl

Because of security considerations, I would like to disable WebGL support in Chrome. I have seen that on Windows and Linux, it can be done with the `--disable-webgl` command line option, but I don't know how to do it on Mac. I think that I have to edit one of the `.plist` files in `Google Chrome.app`, but I have no idea which one.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items/271697#271697) of mine, and change the actual argument you want to pass on to Chrome.