# How to set launch options for programs on OS X

Tags: macos, osx-lion, command-line-arguments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I pass command line arguments to Dock items?](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items)

On a Windows PC, if I need to provide any launch options to an application (say, Chrome browser), I can do that by creating a shortcut to Chrome.exe and adding the options to the end of the shortcut's Target property.

How can I do the same thing on a Mac? Specifically I need to pass some launch options to my Firefox/Chrome browser. I'm running Mac OS X 10.7.3.

Answer (score 4):

In Unix systems (of which OS X is one), options to programs are given at the command line, normally preceeded by "-". So, to run firefox with, for example a private session, open a terminal and enter:

```
 $ firefox -private
```

If you want to make this the default, every time you run firefox, you can create a BASH alias. Edit the file `.profile` in your user's home directory and add this line:

```
alias firefox="firefox -private"
```

Once you save that file, everytime you run firefox you will run it with the desired options.

Finally, to get a list of the command line options available to firefox, run `firefox -h` from a terminal. The following is the output on Linux:

```
$ firefox -h
Usage: firefox [ options ... ] [URL]
       where options include:

X11 options
  --display=DISPLAY  X display to use
  --sync             Make X calls synchronous
  --g-fatal-warnings Make all warnings fatal

Firefox options
  -h or -help        Print this message.
  -v or -version     Print Firefox version.
  -P <profile>       Start with <profile>.
  -migration         Start with migration wizard.
  -ProfileManager    Start with ProfileManager.
  -no-remote         Do not accept or send remote commands; implies -new-instance.
  -new-instance      Open new instance, not a new window in running instance.
  -UILocale <locale> Start with <locale> resources as UI Locale.
  -safe-mode         Disables extensions and themes for this session.
  -jsconsole         Open the Error console.
  -browser           Open a browser window.
  -new-window  <url> Open <url> in a new window.
  -new-tab     <url> Open <url> in a new tab.
  -preferences       Open Preferences dialog.
  -search     <term> Search <term> with your default search engine.
  -private           Enable private browsing mode.
  -private-toggle    Toggle private browsing mode.
  -setDefaultBrowser Set this app as the default browser.
```

Comment: Is there a "nonglobal" way of achieving `alias`?

Comment: @Pacerier this isn't global, it only affects your user. But on OSX, you should use `~/.profile`, not `~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line, you can use the following:

```
open -a ProgramName --args your program arguments
```

Since OS X applications are packages as application bundle and their binaries aren't usually on the `$PATH`, the usual "Unix way" of launching applications is usually too complicated unless you're willing to `alias` or `ln -s` everything. Compare (if you installed Firefox to the default applications folder):

```
open -a Firefox
/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

---

For passing command-line options as arguments **without opening Terminal**, see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/271678/how-do-i-pass-command-line-arguments-to-dock-items/271697#271697).